# My PhpStorm 5 does not know php native functions

Tags: phpstorm

I recently downloaded PhpStorm 5. Everything work fine with verion 4, but now I can not access to native php functions on autocomplete.
Functions and classes declared in my project are still there.
Any ideas ?

Comment: You should choose the below answer if it was the solution for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `File` | **Invalidate Caches**, also check that PHP interpreter is configured for the project (`File` | `Settings` | `PHP`, **Interpreter**).

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem in my PhpStorm2020.2 by this command in linux:

on Linux, execute this command: `rm -rf ~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/`

on macOs: `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/`

Answer (score 0):

How [sj59](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042775/sj59) answered higher if you had used multiple versions of Phpstorm on Ubuntu like 2020.1, 2020.2 and then 2020.3 deleting cache can help but it was not working for me until I deleted all JetBrains Cache folder like this:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/JetBrains/
```

Before this I tried Invalidating Caches, turning all plugins off and reinstalling the IDE completely