# PhpStorm do not recognize native PHP functions

Tags: phpstorm

I have no idea why, but PhpStorm do not recognize all PHP native functions. For example, when I type:

```
$len = strlen($str);
```

The `strlen` function is highlighted in orange with the error text `undefined function strlen`.

Everything else is working fine. It's like if everything was loaded except the PHP built-in library.

I'm using the last version of PhpStorm (installed 1 week ago on a new computer).

Regards,

Comment: Screenshots please -- whole IDE window and not just the line with that code. P.S. *"I'm using the last version of PHPStorm"* Please state exact version. There are different "latest" versions -- latest stable; latest EAP build.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542506/my-phpstorm-5-does-not-know-php-native-functions

Comment: *"Everything else is working fine"* In the same file? What about other files? Will it work OK if you rename file or create another brand new file? Will your win classes work in that file? There are multiple possibilities of what might went wrong .. but yes -- `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restarting IDE is the first thing to try.

Comment: @LazyOne Well it seems that a restart with `Invalidate Caches` fixed the problem, thank you!